# Reading bytes as a string from Db

Tags: postgresql, object, byte

I have one table that has 2 fields one(`container_id`) for numeric type and another for byte type(`coDearntainer_objects`) .
I would like to read the byte field(`container_objects`) as a string for corresponding (`container_id`)
field.

How could I do this? I am using Postgresql Db
Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE container
(
  ct_id numeric,
  container_object bytea
)
```

Comment: String sql="select container_objects from contanier where ct_id=232"; 
  ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
  while(rs.next())   
  {
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
   Vector scontObject=new Vector();
   scontObject.add("container_objects");
   oout.writeObject(scontObject);
   System.out.println(oout.toString());
   //System.out.println(baos.toString());
   oout.close();
  } i tried like this i got following result                                         java.io.ObjectOutputStream@efd552

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [encode()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-binarystring.html) to transform a bytea to a string.